# ExpressJS How to render every njk template file if exist

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

I want to render any njk file with express+nunjucks
Examples I found online contain only:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.njk');
});
```

But how to implement this?
Thank you

```js
const express = require('express');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

/*
options and other code is here
*/

// index.njk, contacts.njk, ..., anything.njk
app.get('any *.njk file', function (req, res) {
    
    if('any *.njk file exists' == true) {
        res.render('any *.njk file');
    } else {
       console.log('error 404');
       res.render('404.njk');
    }
});
```

**update:**

What I have now is:

```js
app.get(/^\/.+\.njk$/, function (req, res) {
    let file = req.url.replace(/\//, '');
    // if(fileExists == true)
    res.render(file);
});
```

Easiest way to get file from request:

```js
app.get("/:templateName", function (req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.templateName);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [route parameters.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

For example:

```js
app.get("/:templateName", function (req, res) {
  // Check if the file exists, render it etc.
  console.log(req.params.templateName);
});
```